# Schengen Visa - Application

Tags: schengen

I was in UK last year on an ICT short term (1 year) work permit which expired in June this year owing to which I came back to India. When I was in UK I had applied for a Schengen visa for a euro tour which is still valid as the expiry on it is after 6 months from now.

Can I use this Schengen visa to travel to Amsterdam from India now? Does it matter that it was applied from the UK and not India?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can travel to Amsterdam or any other Schengen state as long as your visa is valid. However, do make sure that the visa issued to you is a multiple entry visa if you have already visited a Schengen country using this visa.

Comment: There's also the 90/180 rule to consider, but if the traveler hasn't been in Europe since June -- that is, has been outside the Schengen area for more than 90 days -- it's not necessary to count any previous time spent in the Schengen area.